# Extra text field for Status order in Commerce

Tags: commerce

I do have extra order status (Available for download) in Commerce. And when I choose this status I want to add a link to download a file. How can I add extra field for the order?

Probably, I even need two fields: "link" for the link and "text" for the description of link.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.